# "Selecting deleted buffer" error in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Emacs, I'm trying to create a file on the fly (using `with-temp-file`), set some file local variables, write the local variables to the file and save it. After some modifications to the newly created file, I delete the file and kill the corresponding buffer. So far it's working.

Now after deleting the file, I do the same process (create file on the fly, open the buffer, etc). But this time when I try to do something on the newly created buffer using `with-current-buffer` I'm getting this weird error:

> Selecting deleted buffer

`buffer-live-p` on the new buffer returns `t`.

What could have gone wrong?

I'm using a custom build of Emacs 24.3 on RHEL 6.

Comment: It seems most likely that you've captured the buffer object for the original (and now deleted) buffer, and have passed that object to `with-current-buffer`, rather than the object for the new buffer.

Comment: I was about to submit the code and identified the error. It was exactly what you've pointed out. Thanks for that.